# Install Ubuntu alongside Windows 10 - without creating partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I had no access to my Windows 10 installation on an old PC, but had to get it up and running.  I'm installing Ubuntu via live usb and just went with the "install alongside Windows 10 option and keep all data".

Not too bothered if I lose Windows 10 from this, but I didn't do the usual steps to create a partition / space for ubuntu, so I've no idea where this is being installed.  Is my Windows 10 / associated files likely gone?

Comment: It is a normal installation way. Nothing should be gone. Partitions create automatically. Who told you that you needed to manually partition disk on every installation?

Comment: Phew! Ok, great - thanks for confirming @Pilot6

Comment: A wrong way is to "replace Windows with Ubuntu", etc.

Comment: The files should be there, but there is no guarantee that Windows partition will mount from a broken Win10, but it is fixable.